# titlesec versus titling; mangling \thetitle

Tags: header-footer, titlesec, incompatibility, titling

I want to have the chapter name and title of the document appear in the header; I know how to do that with `fancyhdr` and `titling`, one of the miscellaneous functions of the latter is to preserve the `\thetitle` command which can be used to extract the title of the document later on.

Now I added on the `titlesec` package to make the section/chapter headings look better. But here I run into a problem: `titlesec` seems to be overwriting `\thetitle` with the contents of `\thesection` or `\thesubsection`!

An example to show the problem:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newpagestyle{testfancy}{%
  \headrule% 
  \sethead{\thetitle}{}{\chaptertitle}}
\pagestyle{testfancy}

\title{My title}
\author{This author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{A chapter}

some filler text

\newpage

some more filler text

\newpage

\section{Now a section is added}
\end{document}
```

On page 3, the left header is displayed (as defined and intended) to be the value of `\thetitle`, which in this case is "My title". On page 4, however, after the new section, the left header now shows as "1.1", the value of `\thesection`.

Is this conflict documented somewhere? And is there a fix/workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kind of hack-ish, but it works. (You might not need `titling` any more if this is all you were using it for...)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\let\oldtitle\title
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\oldtitle{#1}\newcommand{\mythetitle}{#1}}

\newpagestyle{testfancy}{%
  \headrule% 
  \sethead{\mythetitle}{}{\chaptertitle}}
\pagestyle{testfancy}

\author{This author}
\title{My Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{A chapter}

some filler text

\newpage

some more filler text 

\newpage

\section{Now a section is added}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nah, I'm putting together a class file for writing lecture notes, and am using `titling` to format the output of `\maketitle`, so I'm not just using it for the one command. Redefining `\title` does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if the conflict is documented anywhere, but it is quite clear from reading the source of the two packages. You can replace your use of `\thetitle` with `\mytitle` and at some point after `\title{My title}`, put `\let\mytitle\thetitle`.

[**Edit:** I should point out that like frabjous's answer, you don't need the `titling` package for this. You can use

```
\makeatletter
\let\mytitle\@title
\makeatother
```

after your `\title{My title}` instead.]

Also, when compiling your code, I get the following warning.

```
Package titlesec Warning: You are using an old interface for page styles
(titlesec)                You could proceed but don't complain if you run
(titlesec)                into errors.
```

You might want to fix that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to =( I am following the manual in the latest release, which does make the comment in a footnote that "The way page styles works have been reimplemented in full in release 2.3. However in most cases you won't notice a difference at all." And this is with the documentation that comes with release 2.8...

Comment: In version 2.9 the warning is more meaningful - you forgot the package option pagestyles.