# Problem with making a custom class

Tags: document-classes

I am trying to make a custom class file for a SOP. I think I am running into issues when using fancyhdr package but I'm not sure why.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{sop}[10/10/2014 article class for standard operating procedures]

% Passes and class options to the underlying article class
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{article}

% Redefine the page margins
\RequirePackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=.75in,bottom=.75in]{geometry}

% Modifications to the section titles
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}.0}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}

% Modification of title block
\RequirePackage{titling}
\newcommand{\sopchaptertitle}[1]{\def\@sopchaptertitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\sopchapternumber}[1]{\def\@sopchapternumber{#1}}

%%% Drop before title
\setlength\droptitle{12cm}

%%% Define the internal variable \@title to be the supplied data
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{%
\def\@title{\@sopchaptertitle\ \@sopchapternumber}}

%%% No author field, so \maketitlehookb gobbles what comes after it
\renewcommand\maketitlehookb[1]{}

%%% No date field, so \maketitlehookc gobbles what comes after it
\renewcommand\maketitlehookc[1]{}

%%% Formatting the title
\pretitle{\centering\sffamily\LARGE}

%%% Space after the title
\posttitle{\par\vspace{3cm}}

 %%% The rest of the class    

 % For "Page N of M" and header/footer constructioe
\RequirePackage{lastpage}

% For easier construction of page headers/footers
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\revision}[1]{\def\@revision{#1}}
\newcommand{\revisionMMYY}[1]{\def\@revisionMMYY{#1}}
\newcommand{\tcn}[1]{\def\@tcn{#1}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{ % for first page
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{%
SOP- \thesopchapternumber \ Page \thepage{} of \pageref*{LastPage} 
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{%
REV \therevision,\ \therevisionMMYY
}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\pagestyle{fancy} % for other pages
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{%
SOP-\thesopchapternumber \ Page \thepage{} of \pageref*{LastPage} 
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{%
REV \therevision,\ \therevisionMMYY
}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% For easier customization of itemized, enumerated, and other lists
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
% For hyperlinked cross-references
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
% Ensure first page is correct style
\RequirePackage{appendix}
\RequirePackage{makebox}
\RequirePackage{nextpage}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\endinput
```

Here is a basic Tex file I'm trying to compile with it just to try and get it to work.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{sop}
%
% SOP Standard Form Data
\sopchaptertitle{john doe PROCEDURE}
\sopchapternumber{D.1}

\date{11/13/14}
\author{johndoe}
%...more of the above
%Here begins the actual document
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Main Title}

\section{Approval}
Approval1....\makebox[1.5in]{\hrulefill}\\\vspace{1.5in}
Approval2....\makebox[1.5in]{\hrulefill}

\newpage

\section{Purpose and Discussion}
%...more of the above...
\end{document}
```

edit: Here is my log file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/qebydr5p1xt9ozq/text.log?dl=0

Comment: Could you describe the "issues"?

Comment: `10/10/2014` should be `2014/10/10`

Comment: Related: [Template for Standard Operating Procedures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22532/template-for-standard-operating-procedures) (apparently the class code started from my answer there -- didn't notice at first).

Comment: `\thesopchapternumber` is not defined. If you want to use it like this, `sopchapternumber` needs to be a *counter* defined with `\newcounter`. Similarly for `\therevision` etc. They all need to be counters if you plan to access them this way. Not the problem, but consider using the updated alternative for `lastpage`. You'll see warnings about the use of `lastpage` in your compilation output, with recommendations for updating.

Comment: Right now it is giving me a bunch of undefined control sequence errors in the log, Werner.  I will try to use counters like you suggest, cfr.

Comment: Cfr, I defined \thesopchapternumber as a new command in my original. why do I need it to be define as a counter when I'm just using it as a title and not a counter? Thank you for your help.

Comment: `\fancyhead[R]{%
SOP- \@sopchapternumber \ Page \thepage{} of \pageref*{LastPage} 
}`. Use the @versions you are `def`ing when using `\sopchapternumber{my number}`. The `\the` construct doesn't work here (it doesen't in the linked answer as well <-- @mikerenfro)

Comment: @Johannes_B anything I should change in my referenced answer? Not seeing anything to do with chapter numbers there. Or is this mostly a note for heyjva?

Comment: @MikeRenfro Mostly a note to the OP, but your `\theauthor` is buggy (as far as i can tell).

Comment: @Johannes_B I'm probably being dense. Not sure how `\theauthor` will fail if I have the `titling` package included, and the author's name was inserted in the page headers as needed.

Comment: @MikeRenfro My bad, i have no experience with package `titling`. My test document didn't include an `\author` command, hence `\theauthor` is completely undefined (i would have expected a warning or something similar). The OP here uses `\thesopchapternumber` which seems to be related to `\theauthor`. I understand that this can be confusing for a beginner. Want to write an answer?

Comment: I actually figure out using the @ fixed my code. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several things to fix in your MWE:

1. In the main document, you omitted `\revision` and `\revisionMMYY` commands. Your class file has no default values for these, so they cause errors when referenced.
2. You misunderstand the use of `\thesomething` constructs sometimes found in class or package code. Most of the time, these are used to print the formatted value of counters defined with the `\newcounter{}` command (see [the LaTeX Wikibook: Counters](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters)). As @cfr mentioned, if you had used `\newcounter{sopchapternumber}`, then macros including `\thesopchapternumber`, `\value{sopchapternumber}`, `\arabic{sopchapternumber}`, etc. become available. In my previous example, the [`titling`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling) package also added `\thetitle` and `\theauthor` commands that aren't counters, but these are exceptions to the rule, and were explicitly added by the package code.

Additionally, if these SOPs are chapter-based, I'd consider basing the class off of `book` or `report` where chapters are built in, instead of `article`.

Corrected MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{sop}
\sopchaptertitle{john doe PROCEDURE}
\sopchapternumber{D.1}
\revision{Some Revision}
\revisionMMYY{Some Month, Some Year}
\date{11/13/14}
\author{johndoe}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Main Title}
\section{Approval}
Approval1....\makebox[1.5in]{\hrulefill}\\\vspace{1.5in}
Approval2....\makebox[1.5in]{\hrulefill}
\newpage
\section{Purpose and Discussion}
\end{document}
```

Class:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{sop}[2014/10/10 article class for standard operating procedures]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{article}

% Redefine the page margins
\RequirePackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=.75in,bottom=.75in]{geometry}

% Modifications to the section titles
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}.0}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}

% Modification of title block
\RequirePackage{titling}
\newcommand{\sopchaptertitle}[1]{\def\@sopchaptertitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\sopchapternumber}[1]{\def\@sopchapternumber{#1}}

%%% Drop before title
\setlength\droptitle{12cm}

%%% Define the internal variable \@title to be the supplied data
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{%
\def\@title{\@sopchaptertitle\ \@sopchapternumber}}

%%% No author field, so \maketitlehookb gobbles what comes after it
\renewcommand\maketitlehookb[1]{}

%%% No date field, so \maketitlehookc gobbles what comes after it
\renewcommand\maketitlehookc[1]{}

%%% Formatting the title
\pretitle{\centering\sffamily\LARGE}

%%% Space after the title
\posttitle{\par\vspace{3cm}}

 %%% The rest of the class    

 % For "Page N of M" and header/footer constructioe
\RequirePackage{lastpage}

% For easier construction of page headers/footers
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\revision}[1]{\def\@revision{#1}}
\newcommand{\revisionMMYY}[1]{\def\@revisionMMYY{#1}}
\newcommand{\tcn}[1]{\def\@tcn{#1}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{ % for first page
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{%
SOP- \@sopchapternumber \ Page \thepage{} of \pageref*{LastPage} 
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{%
REV \@revision{},\ \@revisionMMYY
}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\pagestyle{fancy} % for other pages
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{%
SOP-\@sopchapternumber \ Page \thepage{} of \pageref*{LastPage} 
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{%
REV \@revision{},\ \@revisionMMYY
}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% For easier customization of itemized, enumerated, and other lists
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
% For hyperlinked cross-references
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
% Ensure first page is correct style
\RequirePackage{appendix}
\RequirePackage{makebox}
\RequirePackage{nextpage}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\endinput
```