# Document Class for Reference Cards

Tags: document-classes

I've seen a bunch of reference cards (either obviously or known-to-be TeX'd) that look exactly alike in format.  Is there a `documentclass` or environment that's being done to enable this or, if not, how could it be implemented in a LaTeX-y, separate-content-from-formatting kind of way?

- http://orgmode.org/orgcard.pdf
- http://refcards.com/docs/silvermanj/tex/tex-refcard-a4.pdf
- http://www.stdout.org/~winston/latex/latexsheet.pdf
- http://refcards.com/docs/gildeas/gnu-emacs/emacs-refcard-a4.pdf

Comment: This isn't a document class, but it may be a place to start: www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/ReferenceCards/LaTeXRefCard.v2.0.tex - or not. Form and content aren't as separate as perhaps they should be. I hope you get a real answer.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks -- I ran into this before while doing research.  While I recognize that TeX has its place (in the *creation* of document classes, for example), there should either already be a better solution or one should be created.  If it comes down to writing one, I'm sure this source will come in handy (although when I TeX'd it earlier, it seemed to run off the page (as if it was meant for landscape instead of the portrait that came out).

Comment: Thematically related to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/latex-template-for-a-technical-reference-manual-user-guide

Comment: Same quastion with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911516/how-to-make-cheat-sheets-in-latex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a start. [Class version](https://github.com/vermiculus/refsheet/blob/master/refsheet.cls) tested and seems to produce the same output, with a few changes to `\maketitle`. Edits welcome.

[image: Example output]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[orthodox,l2tabu,abort]{nag}

% Page layout
\usepackage[landscape,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

% Title area
\usepackage{titling} % Allows for use of date, author, etc. after \maketitle
% Ref: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3988/titlesec-versus-titling-mangling-thetitle
\let\oldtitle\title
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\oldtitle{#1}\newcommand{\mythetitle}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
{\begin{center}\Large \mythetitle\end{center}}
}

% Document divisions
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\usepackage{nopageno} % To keep \section from resetting page style

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % disabling indentation by default

% Lists
\usepackage{enumitem} % for consistent formatting of lists
\newlist{ttdesc}{description}{1}
\setlist[ttdesc]{font=\ttfamily,noitemsep}
\usepackage{calc} % for \widthof

% Code
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,%
  basicstyle=\itshape,%
  keywordstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,%
  morekeywords={part,chapter,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}%
  }

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{\LaTeXe Cheat Sheet}
\author{Winston Chang}
\date{2012}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\maketitle

\section{Document classes}

\begin{ttdesc}[labelwidth=\widthof{\texttt{report}}]
\item[book] Default is two-sided.
\item[report] No \texttt{part} divisions.
\end{ttdesc}

\subsection{Common \texttt{documentclass} options}

\begin{ttdesc}[labelwidth=\widthof{\ttfamily{letterpaper/a4paper}}]
\item[10pt/11pt/12pt] Font size.
\item[letterpaper/a4paper] Paper size.
\item[draft] Double-space lines.
\end{ttdesc}

\section{Document structure}

\vspace{-\baselineskip}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\lstinline|\part{title}| \\
\lstinline|\chapter{title}| \\
\lstinline|\section{title}| \\
\lstinline|\subsection{title}| \\
\lstinline|\subsubsection{title}| \\
\lstinline|\paragraph{title}| \\
\lstinline|\subparagraph{title}|
\end{multicols*}

\section{Text properties}

\subsection{Font face}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
Command & Declaration & Effect \\
\lstinline|\textrm{text}| & \lstinline|{\rmfamily text}| & \textrm{Roman family} \\
\lstinline|\textsf{text}| & \lstinline|{\sffamily text}| & \textsf{Sans serif family} \\
\end{tabular}

\section{Math mode}

\subsection{Math mode symbols}
\begin{multicols*}{4}
\( \leq \) \verb|\leq| \\
\( \times \) \verb|\times| \\
\( ^{\circ} \) \verb|^{\circ}| \\
\( \infty \) \verb|\infty| \\
\( \supset \) \verb|\supset| \\
\( \subset \) \verb|\subset| \\
\( \cup \) \verb|\cup| \\
\( \dot a \) \verb|\dot a| \\
\( \alpha \) \verb|\alpha| \\
\( \epsilon \) \verb|\epsilon| \\
\( \theta \) \verb|\theta| \\
\( \lambda \) \verb|\lambda| \\
\( \pi \) \verb|\pi| \\
\( \upsilon \) \verb|\upsilon|
\end{multicols*}

\section{Filler material}

\lipsum

\noindent Copyright \textcopyright{} \thedate{} \theauthor{}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, this answers the question.  Learned quite a few new things!  Any help over at Github (https://github.com/vermiculus/refsheet) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @SeanAllred I have extended the class and sent you a pull-request. Maybe you have a few minutes to check it out. All others are welcome to check, too: https://github.com/polyluxus/refsheet

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I'm reviewing it now :-)

Answer (score 0):

The most notable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16930546/1959808) to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1911516/1959808) appears to be https://michaelgoerz.net/refcards/.